# SQL Error when trying to insert one value into one row for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and for some reason my `INSERT` statement isn't working as before even though the syntax looks correct. It's error-ing out on the `where` statement...

**SQL**:

```
insert into users(age) values('16') where username='r';
```

Answer (score 5):

If the row for username r already exists perhaps you are looking to update the `age` value instead?

Use: `update users set age = 16 where username =  'r'` instead.

Also, I'm just guessing here, but maybe `age` holds a numeric value, and if so you can remove the quotes around 16.

Answer (score 4):

That syntax isn't correct.  You can't use `where` like that.  Perhaps you want something like:

```
insert into users (username, age)
values ('r', '16')
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Alternatively if that user already exists, you might be looking for an `update` statement instead:

```
update users set age = '16' where username = 'r'
```

Comment: I'm pulling the username from a session and then for that user I need to insert the value into a specific column, would 'update' work?

Comment: @DRE -- are you wanting to `insert` a new record in your table or are you looking to `update` an existing record in the table?  This depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT` statements must not contain a `WHERE` clause. Remove it.

If, in fact what you are trying to do is update an existing row, use an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT` statement.

```
update users set age = '16' where username='r';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert new records in your table, you have to write query for inserting data.

**[SQL INSERT INTO Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)**  syntax is this:

*INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);*

In your case, if you don't have the record in your database, your query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, age)
VALUES ('r', '16')
```

But if you want to update existing records in your table, you have to write query for updating data using the **[SQL UPDATE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)**.

The syntax for this is:

*UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;*

**To update the record/s, you have to specify clause in *WHERE* which record should be modified.**

To modify age of user/s with username that is equals 'r', this is the query:

```
UPDATE users SET age = 16 WHERE username =  'r'
```

but if you want to modify for all users which usernames starts with 'r':

```
UPDATE users SET age = 16 WHERE username =  'r%'
```

I hope this explanation will help you to understand better SQL statements for **INSERT** new and **UPDATE** existing records.